# Any variable assignment would be empty inside docker

Tags: bash, docker, variable

I have a long script that would be copied inside the docker image in `Dockerfile` and would be executed there.

I'm using bash. Both in my local machine, and inside my docker.

I run this code to ensure that the `bash` executes my script inside the docker build process:

```
RUN bash /path_to_script
```

And it works. But there is this very annoying problem that I can't solve.

I can't create variables inside my bash. They are all empty. I need to repeat a lot of code in my script.

For example, let's say there is a `path` variable, from which I want to get the directory name.

```
export path='/some/path/to/a/dir_or_file'
export dirName=$(basename $path) # this becomes empty
echo $dirName # prints empty
echo $(basename $path) # prints dir_or_file
```

This means that wherever I need `$(basename $path)` I should copy/paste it.

I'm stuck at this point and have no idea how to debug this.

Comment: I can't reproduce this using a Ubuntu base image. I'm assuming you are copying the script into the container in a strange way, possibly using an unquoted here-document redirection? Also, remember to quote expansions, and don't ever use `echo $(...)` (`basename` outputs its result without the help of `echo`).  Also note that the `zsh` shell (which you admittedly aren't using) has a _special_ array called `path` that you definitely do not want to clobber.

Comment: Basically, I use `COPY . /` to copy everything from the docker context into the docker image, and the script is part of those files. It's a simple copy/paste. Thank you for your notes.

Comment: Can you add all the steps you used to create and run the container as well as how you created the script and all its content? I've tested it by creating and running a docker image and I was unable to reproduce your behavior.